# Using Bleed or Tile in Adobe Illustrator CC?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am creating a wall mural for a large wall. My mural will be printed on 24" wide panels. I am perplexed on how to get an inch overlap printed for each. I've researched bleed and tiling, but don't see anything that works the way I'm expecting. I need the left and right edges of artboards to overlap so that the image, when overlapping is cut off, lines up precisely. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Have you asked your print supplier to find out what you need to give them? The companies that I have used generally want the complete image, which they will position on the sheets and trim as required. I've never had to worry about bleeds or tiling.

Answer (score 1):

There is ***already*** support for tiling with overlap in Illustrator in the print tiling options:

From Adobe's Help Center for Illustrator:

> Tile artwork on multiple pages
>   If you are printing artwork from a single artboard (or ignored artboards) that cannot fit on a single page, you can tile the artwork onto multiple pages. If your document has multiple art
>
> **1** Choose File > Print.
>   **2** Select Tile option:
>
> **Note:**
>
> If your document has multiple artboards, first select Ignore Artboards, or specify 1 page in the Range option and select Fit To Page.
>
> **Full Pages**
>
> Divides the artboard into full media-sized pages for output.
>
> **Imageable Areas**
>
> Divides the artboard into pages based on what the selected device can image. This option is useful for outputting artwork that is larger than your device can handle, because it allows you to reassemble tiled pieces into the original larger artwork.
>
> **3** (Optional) If you selected Full Pages, ***set the Overlap option*** (emphasis mine) to specify the amount of overlap between pages.

https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/setting-documents-printing.html

Target a PDF virtual printer and you'll end up with a multi-page PDF with appropriate overlaps set up; you can review it in Acrobat for accuracy and re-do until you're happy with the results.

Printing with tiling:
[image]

Result:
[image]
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

[See here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/99026/double-page-spread-bleed-in-illustrator) -- you can use single artboards with a bleed. And the bleed will work as you expect.

Merely set up artboards to match the tile size minus the bleed size, then butt the artboards against each other. The bleed will create the overlaps.

[image]

[image]

[image]